# Class extensions leaking to framework's public API in Swift submodules

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, module

I have a Swift-only project that builds a framework. The project has 3 targets:

- Core: static library (libCore.a), defines module `Core`

  ```swift
  // core.swift
  public struct CoreStruct {}
  public func coreFunc() {}
  ```
- Ext: static library (libExt.a), defines module `Ext`

  ```swift
  // ext.swift
  import Core
  public extension CoreStruct {
      public func internalStuff() {}
  }
  public func extFunc() {}
  ```
- MyFramework: Cocoa dynamic framework that is linked with `libCore.a` and `libExt.a`

Now, I want the public interface of `MyFramework` to only expose Core because the stuff in `Ext` is implementation detail that should only be visible to `MyFramework`. So I added this to the umbrella header:

```c
// MyFramework.h
...
@import Core;
```

At this point, `CoreStruct` and `coreFunc()` are visible to consumers of `MyFramework`. The problem is that so is `CoreStruct.internalStuff()`! But, interestingly enough, `extFunc()` is not! So it appears that extensions behave somewhat differently to regular functions when it comes to access control.

I have already tried creating custom modulemap files, like so:

```
// MyFramework.modulemap
framework module MyFramework {
  umbrella header "MyFramework.h"
  export *
  module Core { export * }
}

// MyFramework.private.modulemap
explicit module MyFramework.Ext {
  export *
}
```

but it didn't change anything.

My questions:

1. how can I make `Ext`'s extensions available to `MyFramework` but hidden from the world?
2. is the exposure of `internalStuff()` a bug or a feature?